# Show textfield on correct category from DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

How to show my widget only when in my dropdown button is selected one of the option?

i try this:

```
  showWidgetOnCategory() async {
    if(_selectedCategory == 'FREE'){
       _buildCountPerson();
    }
  }

  Widget _dropdownCategory(){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:0), 
      child: DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        hint: Text('Type', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade300),),
        value: _selectedCategory,

        onChanged: (newValue){
          setState(() async {
            _selectedCategory = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: _categories.map((category){
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text(category, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
            value: category,
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
    );
  }


  _buildCountPerson(){
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Text('Liczba miejsc:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 120,
                height: 50,
                child: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: _countPersonOnEventController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '0',
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)
                      ),
                  ),
                  validator: (String value) {
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return 'Pole wymagane';
                      }else return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _count = int.parse(value);
                      print(_count);
                    },
                  )
              )

        ],
      ));
  }
```

but it not work, 
have anybody any idea how to help me?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a boolean droDownSelected = false initially and then in onChanged method of DropDown set it to true so other widget can be shown. You can show widgets by condition in the following way.

```
bool droDownSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton(), // in onChanged method setState droDownSelected to true so below widget is shown
        droDownSelected ? WidgetYouWantToShow() : SizedBox(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: I works, thanks, but when i comebck to the different options thats widget is still visible, why? i want to see him only in one option, he must hide when i change to the other

Comment: It is still visible because we haven't added condition that it should only be visible on specific value. You can wrap the line where dropDownSelected is being true with if condition like this: if(newValue== 'FREE'){
       dropDownSelected = true;
    } else {  dropDownSelected = false;}